# how to handle driver to skip the current test and move to next test in current test class whenever it reaches on a dead end web page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit-2.5, nunit-3.0

**Issue description:** I have a test class which has multiple test cases. During the execution of one test the 'Page Could not be loaded' error occurs and driver times out as it does not find any element on page. While I can handle this particular situation by putting try catch statements but I need a way to instruct the driver that whenever it reaches on any such page it shall perform a set of actions (re-visit the site, perform login) and resume the testing from the very next test in current test class where it was stuck.

I'm using Selenium with C# and Nunit 3.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [EventFiringWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriver.cs) and leverage [WebDriverExceptionEventArgs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/Events/WebDriverExceptionEventArgs.cs) to eavesdrop into exceptions and see if that helps ? You can refer to the unit test [EventFiringWebDriverTest](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/test/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriverTest.cs) to learn how to use it. That way your tests don't need to change.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, This answer seems that it can resolve my issue but even after a long exploration I could not figure out that how to implement it.

Comment: It's designed for a different purpose Krishnan. I think applying a global exception handler will resolve the issue. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Its basically a mechanism which gives you a chance to tap into events as and when they happen. Occurance of an exception is also one such event. So I believe it should help you. Did you give it a shot ? If yes, what was the outcome ? What were the issues you faced. Maybe you could share that, so that you can be given further help

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
   //your code
}
catch(TimeoutException ex)
{
   //go to home url
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Leon, But using this I can handle it on test case level but I want a mechanism to write such code once throughout my test project. I think there must be a way to define it in base class (where driver is primarily created and initialized).